# What is the inverse of the following function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the inverse function of $ y=x^3+x$? thanks

Comment: Do you really need its inverse?

Answer (score 2):

According to Wolfram Mathematica, the equation $x^3+x=y$ is solved by
$$
x=\frac{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 y^2+4}+9 y}}{\sqrt[3]{2}
   3^{2/3}}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3}}}{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 y^2+4}+9 y}}.
$$

Comment: Proof by wolfram alpha. Did you at least verify that it is actually correct?

Comment: @Tim: Please explain about Solution. thanks

Comment: @nim it isn't my answer. There is nothing wrong with it as far as I can see, I was only criticizing the presentation.

Comment: Of course Mathematica can handle standard computations much better than I would :-)

Answer (score -2):

I get $x= y-y^3+3y^5-12y^7+55y^9-273y^{11}+-...$ where the coefficients are given by http://oeis.org/A001764 with alternating signs.
This is of course convergent up to the point where the closed form solution has its poles. The reference shows that, as a generating function, the coefficients have nice closed forms in terms of binomial coefficients.

Comment: This isn't even convergent, is it? I am not convinced a series solution is so useful when closed form analytic solutions are possible.